# AOSP: How to build /platform/frameworks/base or /platform/frameworks/support separately in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-source

Is there a way to build [AOSP's /platform/frameworks/base package source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support) or [support library source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support) separately in Android Studio.

I wanted to read the framework (base and support) code in Android Studio and since I didn't want to be bothered about the rest of the packages in AOSP, I only imported the mirrored repo of these two packages as two separate projects in Android Studio. I want to browse through the code by using "jump to source" shortcut (cmd/ctrl+click) of the IDE. But this handy feature won't simply work properly in Android Studio. When I try to jump to the method definition which belongs to a different java source file (It says - "Cannot find declaration to go to"). This limitation of source editor is due to gradle build failure. The project just won't build and throws the following error.

> Error:You need a symlink in prebuilts/sdk/99 that points to
>   prebuilts/sdk/current.Without it, studio cannot understand current
>   SDK. ln -s ../../prebuilts/sdk/current ../../prebuilts/sdk/99

Is there a way to fix this. I know I can simply browse the source code on http://androidxref.com/ too, but it's not as convenient and powerful as your IDE.

Comment: Browsing it will be a lot easier than *building* it.  In either case, see the sidebar - this is the type of question that has been covered in its limitations and possibilities many times before.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible (having Android Studio be able to show you the framework code and let you use the usual IDE tools), though compiling won't work.
But the detail in your question seems to indicate you don't actually care about compiling, just about viewing/editing.

The first steps listed here:
http://ronubo.blogspot.com/2016/01/debugging-aosp-platform-code-with.html
might work for you.  Basically:

1. Build your AOSP platform 
   ( . build/envsetup.sh && lunch - && make ...)
2. Create the Android Studio project for importing to
   ( mmm development/tools/idegen &&  development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh )
3. Import the project
   ( open android.ipr from Android Studio)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. So that means I will still have to clone the entire AOSP. Right? What would be the size of it ? Around 25GB or more? Can i use an external hard disk for this since my machine only has about 10-12 GB of free space (it's only 128gb SSD. :( ).

Comment: It's quite large. You don't need the vast majority of it, but sorting out which parts you do need is not straightforward.  Once you've run idegen you don't need anything beyond the sources you actually care about, of course, so you can do that part anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not without a **huge** effort.

For very many reasons.Ex:

1.the framework depends on different HALs and libraries from system/bionic/external

2.Compiling the framework uses specific tools from linux(flex,bison,libgl etc..)

3.Framework is built using the Android.mk system and needs a lot of flags and compilation macros from build/

I also can't imagine a motivation to do what you are trying to do. If it's going to run on any device, bare in mind device manufacturers modify the framework heavily, even the small ones. Actually the chipset manufacturers modify it and give it to manufacturers that modify it even more.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:You need a symlink in prebuilts/sdk/99 that points to prebuilts/sdk/current.Without it, studio cannot understand current SDK. ln -s ../../prebuilts/sdk/current ../../prebuilts/sdk/99

This notice already tell you should run the command:

`ln -s ../../prebuilts/sdk/current ../../prebuilts/sdk/99`

To tell build system use 'current version sdk' in `prebuilts/sdk/current` directory replace the temp sdk version 99.

could you try it?